# Migrate communities built with Napili template

Tags: apex, visualforce, deployment, change-set, ant

How to migrate communities built with Napili template using Ant migration tool

Comment: Hi, Did you find a way to migrate the pages built in napili template from one org to other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this blog on migrating Napili template configurations: http://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2015/12/22/deploy-community-builder-templates-in-3-simple-steps/

I have not tried but would love to hear if this method of deployment works.

EDIT:

**Step 1:** Use change sets to move all custom lightning components you are referencing in the community from the sandbox to production, as well as any metadata that you setup outside of the Community Builder (welcome email templates, workflow rules, profiles, permission sets, etc). If you skip this step, it will still allow you to deploy the community and will appear to be successful, but you will see an internal server error in the Community Builder and will not be able to make any updates until you have moved the missing components into production. I highly recommend creating a deployment template and filling it in as you build your community to ensure nothing is forgotten at the time of deployment; it is an important part of our methodology at Perficient and ensures smooth deployments.Export This Site in Site.com Studio

**Step 2:** From your sandbox, navigate to the Site.com Studio and locate the toolbar. Click the arrow next to the widget icon and select to ‘Export This Site’ from the sandbox. Then go into production and create a new community, selecting the same version of the template; going from a Spring ’16 Napili template in sandbox and moving Winter ’16 production environment will not work. You need to go from Winter’ 16 in sandbox to Winter ’16 in production. All customization performed inside the Community Builder will move over.

**Step 3:** Go to the Community Management console and update your administrative settings, topics, moderation criteria, etc. as these do not carry over automatically.

Comment: If you want to post an answer based on a link please include some of the relevant content - [answer]

Comment: In **Step 2:** what I need to do in the target environment for making the exported community deployed? I did created a new community, but how can I deploy the **.site** file into this new one?

Answer (score 1):

The community info is provided in the [Network Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm) .I would imagine this needs to be migrated between orgs .

The package.xml to retrive would look something like below

```
<types>
    <members>your community name here</members>
    <name>Network</name>
</types>
```

The metadata would be something like below for Napili

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Network xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<allowMembersToFlag>false</allowMembersToFlag>
<branding>
    <loginFooterText>salesforce.com</loginFooterText>
      <loginLogo>Communities_Shared_Document_Folder/communityname_logic_logo_jpg.jpg</loginLogo>
    <primaryColor>#1797C0</primaryColor>
    <primaryComplementColor>#FFFFFF</primaryComplementColor>
    <quaternaryColor>#B1BAC1</quaternaryColor>
    <quaternaryComplementColor>#222222</quaternaryComplementColor>
    <secondaryColor>#51606E</secondaryColor>
    <tertiaryColor>#DDE4E9</tertiaryColor>
    <tertiaryComplementColor>#222222</tertiaryComplementColor>
    <zeronaryColor>#51606E</zeronaryColor>
    <zeronaryComplementColor>#FFFFFF</zeronaryComplementColor>
</branding>
   <changePasswordTemplate>All/CommunityChangePasswordEmailTemplate</changePasswordTemplate>
<emailSenderAddress>mohith@codescience.com</emailSenderAddress>
<emailSenderName>communityname internal</emailSenderName>
<enableGuestChatter>false</enableGuestChatter>
<enableInvitation>false</enableInvitation>
<enableKnowledgeable>false</enableKnowledgeable>
<enableNicknameDisplay>false</enableNicknameDisplay>
<enablePrivateMessages>true</enablePrivateMessages>
<enableReputation>true</enableReputation>
<forgotPasswordTemplate>All/CommunityForgotPasswordEmailTemplate</forgotPasswordTemplate>
<networkMemberGroups>
    <profile>admin</profile>
    <profile>customer community user</profile>
</networkMemberGroups>
<picassoSite>communityname_internal1</picassoSite>
<reputationLevels>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>0.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>51.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>151.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>401.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>801.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>1501.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>2501.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>4001.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>6001.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
    <level>
        <lowerThreshold>10001.0</lowerThreshold>
    </level>
</reputationLevels>
<reputationPointsRules>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemMentionSomeone</eventType>
        <points>1</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemWriteAPost</eventType>
        <points>1</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemMarkAnswerAsBest</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>EndorsedForKnowledgeOnATopic</eventType>
        <points>20</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemLikeSomething</eventType>
        <points>1</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemReceiveAComment</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemReceiveAMention</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemYourAnswerMarkedBest</eventType>
        <points>20</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemWriteAComment</eventType>
        <points>1</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemReceiveALike</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemPostQuestion</eventType>
        <points>1</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemSomeoneSharesYourPost</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemShareAPost</eventType>
        <points>1</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>EndorseSomeoneForKnowledgeOnATopic</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemAnswerAQuestion</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
    <pointsRule>
        <eventType>FeedItemReceiveAnAnswer</eventType>
        <points>5</points>
    </pointsRule>
</reputationPointsRules>
<selfRegistration>false</selfRegistration>
<sendWelcomeEmail>true</sendWelcomeEmail>
<site>communityname_internal</site>
<status>UnderConstruction</status>
<tabs>
    <defaultTab>home</defaultTab>
    <standardTab>Chatter</standardTab>
</tabs>
    <urlPathPrefix>communityname</urlPathPrefix>
   <welcomeTemplate>All/CommunityWelcomeEmailTemplate</welcomeTemplate>
```

You may just use normal ANT process to retrieve Network Metadata and Zones if you have used chatter answers and done some config and necessary dependencies and try running ANT deploy.

Comment: after migrating the look and feel is different , I guess all the pages are not migrated. Is there something more needed in the package.xml for complete replica

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types><members>Communities_Shared_Document_Folder</members>
<members>Communities_Shared_Document_Folder/Small_RRD_Logo_png.png</members>
<name>Document</name></types><types>
<members>unfiled$public/CommunityChangePasswordEmailTemplate</members<members>unfiled$public/CommunityForgotPasswordEmailTemplate</members<members>unfiled$public/CommunityWelcomeEmailTemplate</member><name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types><types><members>careCenter</members<name>Network</name>
</types><version>35.0</version></Packa

Comment: you got to figure dependencies as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply . both org are identical , we need to find out the dependencies between ?

Comment: dependencies between metadata mentioned in network files .Like include images referred ,profiles ,lightning components ,pages ,etc

Comment: @MohithShrivastava:  
How do I retrieve the featured topics and images associated with them?